# chapter cover page that spans two pages

Tags: chapters, covers, chapter-page

I am writing up my PhD thesis and I'd like to make a two-page cover page for each chapter, similar to what was done in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550596/chapter-cover-pages-with-image-and-chapter-numbering?rq=1) question, but I can't get their example to work. (I am using the report class)

I have in mind something like the attached image but I'm comfortable with playing around with the background and layout once I know how to add the extra cover page so the design isn't super important at this stage, just getting the extra page on the left. So far I have only been able to add a single cover chapter page like in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89761/chapters-title-page-before-every-chapter-and-every-chapter-with-its-title) question. I've spent all day trying things and I'm not winning so I'd appreciate any tips!

This is what I have tried so far, but I am getting an extra blank page after following the suggestion by David Carslisle:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % remove indent on new paragraph line 
%%%%%% labels "thumbs" for each chapter: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119880/show-current-chapter-number-on-each-page-margin
\usepackage[height={1.5cm},distance={10mm},topthumbmargin={auto},bottomthumbmargin={auto}]{thumbs}
%%%%%% add a blank page 
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    %\addtocounter{page}%
    \newpage}

%%%%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664274/how-do-i-make-it-so-that-every-chapter-starts-at-an-odd-numbered-page-preceded
\def\cleartoeven{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page
     \thispagestyle{plain}\hbox{}\newpage
     \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}


%%%%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89761/chapters-title-page-before-every-chapter-and-every-chapter-with-its-title
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\chapter}{page}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [display]
    {\centering\huge\bfseries}
    {\chaptername\ \thechapter}
    {0pt}
    {\Large}
    [\clearpage]

\title{title}
\author{author}
\date{ \today}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents


\cleartoeven %for the left page
\chapter{Introduction} % for the chapter page on the right
\clearpage %for rest of chapter
\addthumb{Chapter \thechapter}{\Large{\thechapter}}{white}{gray}
\lipsum[]

\end{document}
```

[image: example cover page for chapter spanning 2 pages]

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` gets you to an odd right hand page, you want `\cleartoeven` which is provided by some document classes or search this site for a definition, then you want `\cleartoeven ... stuff on left \clearpage stuff on right \clearpage ... rest of chapter..`.  see https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Ccleartoeven

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your quick reply! That sounds perfect! However I am still getting an extra blank page after the stuff on the right. I think it's because I had the option "twoside" in the documentclass, as it goes away when I put "oneside" but then the chapter "thumbs" end up being on the wrong side. Is \cleartoeven possible with twoside?

Comment: I added a small example of what I have tried so far

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see where to put `\cleartoeven` in the definition of the chapter layout

Comment: titlesec isn't behaving as I'd expect, I'll look later if no one else has answered. Thanks for posting the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without titlesec I think you want

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % remove indent on new paragraph line 
%%%%%% labels "thumbs" for each chapter: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119880/show-current-chapter-number-on-each-page-margin

\usepackage[height={1.5cm},distance={10mm},topthumbmargin={auto},bottomthumbmargin={auto}]{thumbs}
%%%%%% add a blank page 
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    %\addtocounter{page}%
    \newpage}

%%%%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664274/how-do-i-make-it-so-that-every-chapter-starts-at-an-odd-numbered-page-preceded
\def\cleartoeven{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page
     \thispagestyle{plain}\hbox{}\newpage
     \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}


%%%%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89761/chapters-title-page-before-every-chapter-and-every-chapter-with-its-title
\iffalse
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\chapter}{page}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [display]
    {\centering\huge\bfseries}
    {\chaptername\ \thechapter}
    {0pt}
    {\Large}

    \fi
    
\title{title}
\author{author}
\date{ \today}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents


\cleartoeven %for the left page
stuff here on left
\chapter{Introduction} % for the chapter page on the right
\addthumb{Chapter \thechapter}{\Large{\thechapter}}{white}{gray}
\clearpage
\lipsum[]

\end{document}
```

with it, I'm not sure: it's inserting a `\cleardoublepage` somewhere but I can't see why at the moment.

Comment: thank you this is perfect! it was titlesec adding an extra page somewhere so I'm really happy with your solution that doesn't use it!